# How can I assign an ansible variable which is avaiable across tasks?

Tags: ansible

New to ansible - I'm trying to set the `PS1` variable in `/etc/bash.bashrc` based on the condition of the host's IP address. But I am having trouble with the `ps1` variable being available across tassks. I don't know if this is a scope issue (as far as I can tell from [this link](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-scopes)) or if I should really have two separate playbooks basically doing the same thing (one for LAN hosts, one for WIFI hosts). When I run this playbook I get:

`The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error: 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'\n\n`

Is there a way to define the `ps1` variable so I can assign it inside a task and have it available to other tasks?

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: generate LAN host bash prompt
      when: ansible_default_ipv4.address is match("192.168.16")
      connection: local
      shell : /usr/local/bin/psgen -l
      register: ps1
    - debug: var=ps1.stdout

    - name: generate WIFI host bash prompt
      when: ansible_default_ipv4.address is match("172.10.1")
      connection: local
      shell : /usr/local/bin/psgen -w
      register: ps1

    - name: write PS1 to remote /etc/bash.bashrc
      lineinfile:
        dest: /etc/bash.bashrc
        line: "{{ ps1.stdout }}"
        regexp: "PS1="
        insertafter: EOF
```

Comment: You seem to be setting (registering) the ps1 in two tasks?   Is the second over-writing a value you expected to see from the first?  Which task did you actually want the value from?

Comment: Maybe that's the issue. I didn't think it was overwriting the variable since the conditional on the IP address would only match once (in the `when` clause). Any way to tell it to leave the variable alone or do I need two separate playbooks for each subnet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were going to do this, I wouldn't add tasks.  Instead I would remove one, making your task into a loop.  When you loop over something all the results will then be stored in a list.  You can then use various jinja expressions to extract the successful result from the list.

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: generate host bash prompt
    when: ansible_default_ipv4.address is match(item.net_match)
    connection: local
    shell : "{{item.shell}}"
    register: ps1
    loop:
    - name: LAN
      shell: /usr/local/bin/psgen -l
      net_match: 192.168.16
    - name: WAN
      shell: /usr/local/bin/psgen -w
      net_match: 172.10.1

  - debug:
      msg: "ps1"
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ (ps1.results | selectattr('rc', 'defined') | list)[0].stdout }}"

  - name: write PS1 to remote /etc/bash.bashrc
    lineinfile:
      dest: /etc/bash.bashrc
      line: "{{ (ps1.results | selectattr('rc', 'defined') | list)[0].stdout }}"
      regexp: "PS1="
      insertafter: EOF
```

Comment: Good to know about the `loop:` feature, thanks for taking the time to think about this!

Answer (score 2):

@Zoredache is correct.

From: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registered-variables

> If a task fails or is skipped, the variable still is registered with a failure or skipped status, the only way to avoid registering a variable is using tags.

This should work:

```
- name: lan
  set_fact:
    psgen_args: -l
  when: ansible_default_ipv4.address is match("192.168.16")

- name: wlan
  set_fact:
    psgen_args: -w
  when: ansible_default_ipv4.address is match("172.10.1")

- name: set ps1
  shell: /usr/local/bin/psgen {{ psgen_args }}
  register: ps1

- name: write PS1 to remote /etc/bash.bashrc
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/bash.bashrc
    line: "{{ ps1.stdout }}"
    regexp: "PS1="
    insertafter: EOF
```

Comment: Nice approach! I really like how you assigned the command arguments as a fact and then reference the fact with one task. I hadn't thought of doing it that way and it will come in handy for other playbooks.